# Is it safe to use memcpy to insert an element in an array which has greater allocated size?

Tags: c, memcpy

I have an array which contains a preallocated memory size for say 1000 elements.
There is a counter to track the actual number of elements.

Is it safe to use memcpy to insert an alement at a given position?

If I run this, I see that it works, but I am in doubt about if it works by mere chance or it is fundamentally wrong approach as memcpy can not guarantee that the previous data is going to be preserved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int *list;
    int list_size;
    
    // PREALLOCATE SPACE FOR 1000 ITEMS
    list = calloc(sizeof(int), 1000);
    list_size = 0;
    
    // ADD ITEMS
    list[0] = 2; list_size++;
    list[1] = 4; list_size++;
    list[2] = 6; list_size++;
    list[3] = 8; list_size++;
    list[4] = 10; list_size++;
    
    // LIST ITEMS
    printf("---\n"); for(int i=0; i<list_size; i++) printf("%04d\n", list[i]);
    
    // WE WANT TO INSERT A NUMBER AT A GIVEN POSITION (IN THIS CASE WE HAVE A POINTER TO THE ITEM)
    int *p = &list[3];
    
    // WE WANT TO PUSH FORWARD ALL THE ELEMENTS OF THE ARRAY BEFORE INSERTING THE ELEMENT
    memcpy( p+1, p, (list_size - (p - list))*sizeof(int));
    list_size++;
    
    // INSERT ELEMENT
    *p = -1;
    
    // LIST ITEMS
    printf("---\n"); for(int i=0; i<list_size; i++) printf("%04d\n", list[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
---
0002
0004
0006
0008
0010
---
0002
0004
0006
-001
0008
0010
```

Comment: You need `memmove` here, since `memcpy` requires the source range and destination range do not overlap.

Comment: `// WE WANT TO PUSH FORWARD ALL THE ELEMENTS OF THE ARRAY ,,,` <<-- Use `memmove()` instead of `memcpy()`

Comment: No, if you know the size of the destination then you should always check that the location you are copying to and the size will not spill over into unallocated memory.

Comment: As long as you ensure that `list_size` will never exceed 1000, this will be fine if you switch to `memmove()` as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memcpy` has undefined behavior in case the two parameters point to memory that overlaps. You need to use `memmove` instead, it exists for this very purpose.

See the friendly manual or the C standard 7.24.1:

> The `memcpy` function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
> object pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

> The `memmove` function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
> object pointed to by s1. Copying takes place as if the n characters from the object
> pointed to by s2 are first copied into a temporary array of n characters that does not
> overlap the objects pointed to by s1 and s2, and then the n characters from the
> temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by s1.